# Progress bar while uploading a file to dropbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, progress-bar, dropbox, dropbox-api

```
import dropbox
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient('<token>')
f = open('/ssd-scratch/abhishekb/try/1.mat', 'rb')
response = client.put_file('/data/1.mat', f)
```

I want to upload a big file to dropbox. How can I check the progress? [[Docs]](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#ChunkedUploader)

EDIT:
The uploader offeset is same below somehow. What am I doing wrong

```
import os,pdb,dropbox
size=1194304
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(token)
path='D:/bci_code/datasets/1.mat'

tot_size = os.path.getsize(path)
bigFile = open(path, 'rb')

uploader = client.get_chunked_uploader(bigFile, size)
print "uploading: ", tot_size
while uploader.offset < tot_size:
    try:
        upload = uploader.upload_chunked()
        print uploader.offset
    except rest.ErrorResponse, e:
        print("something went wrong")
```

EDIT 2:

```
size=1194304
tot_size = os.path.getsize(path)
bigFile = open(path, 'rb')

uploader = client.get_chunked_uploader(bigFile, tot_size)
print "uploading: ", tot_size
while uploader.offset < tot_size:
    try:
        upload = uploader.upload_chunked(chunk_size=size)
        print uploader.offset
    except rest.ErrorResponse, e:
        print("something went wrong")
```

Comment: @kevin Output: `uploading:  1700302131`

Comment: What is the meaning of the `size` variable? It seems different from `tot_size`.

Comment: @Kevin https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.get_chunked_uploader

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers my question. Can you explain?

Comment: It's uploading the file in chunks. I think it defines the size of chunk. `tot_size` is the total size of the file to be uploaded.

Comment: I think the optional `chunk_size` argument to `upload_chunked` is what defines the chunk size. I think `length` is supposed to be the total file size. (I haven't tested any of this myself though.) What happens if you do `uploader = client.get_chunked_uploader(bigFile, tot_size)`?

Comment: @Kevin there is no output. It keeps uploading no print.

Comment: @Kevin Check edit 2. Let me know if I need to make changes. Right now it doesn't print anything. I think it uploading the whole file at once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`upload_chunked`, as [the documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#ChunkedUploader.upload_chunked) notes:

> Uploads data from this `ChunkedUploader`'s `file_obj` in chunks, until an
>   error occurs. Throws an exception when an error occurs, and can be
>   called again to resume the upload.

So yes, it uploads the entire file (unless an error occurs) before returning.

If you want to upload a chunk at a time on your own, you should use [`upload_chunk`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.upload_chunk) and [`commit_chunked_upload`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.commit_chunked_upload).

Here's some working code that shows you how to upload a single chunk at a time and print progress in between chunks:

```
from io import BytesIO
import os

from dropbox.client import DropboxClient

client = DropboxClient(ACCESS_TOKEN)

path = 'test.data'
chunk_size = 1024*1024 # 1MB

total_size = os.path.getsize(path)
upload_id = None
offset = 0
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    while offset < total_size:
        offset, upload_id = client.upload_chunk(
            BytesIO(f.read(chunk_size)),
            offset=offset, upload_id=upload_id)

        print('Uploaded so far: {} bytes'.format(offset))

# Note the "auto/" on the next line, which is needed because
# this method doesn't attach the root by itself.
client.commit_chunked_upload('auto/test.data', upload_id)
print('Upload complete.')
```